# ReactJs redux : How to call a function from the render function if the prop value change?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two react components which are ProgramSearchBox and DualBox which are generic and wrapper components of predefined npm packages AutoSuggest and DualListBox respectively.

My task to achieve is Based on the value from ProgramSearchBox, I have to list the set values in the DualListBox.

So, If user select a Program from ProgramSearchBox, then I will call API by passing the ProgramId and fetch the set of result values and have to bind them in the DualListBox.

I will get the user selected ProgramID from the ProgramSearchBox as a prop in DualBox component render method.
How to dispatch an action (call a function) from render function in DualBox component by passing the ProgramId?

If I call a method from render function in DualBox, that is becoming Infinite loop!

Here is DualBox component:

```
  //DualBox.js
   class DualBox extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = { selected: [] };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

        this.options = [ ];

        }

      onChange(selected) {
        selected(selected);

      }

      updateOptions()
      {
        console.log("Update Option method called :" + this.props.traineesList );
        this.options = [{ value: 'luna', label: 'Moon' },   { value: 'phobos', label: 'Phobos' }];
        //this.options = this.props.traineeList.map( (value,id) => )
      }
      render() {


            const {ProgramID} = this.props; // HERE I GET ProgramID AS PROP FROM AN ANOTHER COMPONENT
            const {selected} = this.state;

            if(ProgramID !== "") // BASED ON THIS ProgramID VALUE, I NEED TO DISPATCH AN ACTION.
            {
              {this.updateProgramId(ProgramID)} // THIS IS CAUSING INFINITE LOOP
              {this.updateOptions}
            console.log("Program Id came to dualbox:" +ProgramID);
        return <DualListBox options={this.options} selected={selected} onChange={this.onChange} 
            canFilter
                filterCallback={(option, filterInput) => {
                    if (filterInput === '') {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return (new RegExp(filterInput, 'i')).test(option.label);
                }}
                filterPlaceholder="Filter..."
            />;
          }
          else
          {
            console.log("Program Id didn't come to dualbox");
        return <DualListBox options={this.options} selected={selected} onChange={this.onChange} 
            canFilter
                filterCallback={(option, filterInput) => {
                    if (filterInput === '') {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return (new RegExp(filterInput, 'i')).test(option.label);
                }}
                filterPlaceholder="Filter..."
            />;
          }

      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
      return {
        traineesList: state.traineesList
      };
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {

      return {
        updateProgramId: bindActionCreators(( {ProgramID}) => dualBoxActions.getTraineesList(ProgramID), dispatch)
      };
    }


    export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(DualBox);
```

Here is the ProgramSearchBox component:

```
function renderSuggestion(suggestion) {
      return (
        <ul>
          <li>{suggestion.Program}</li>
        </ul>

      );
    }

    class ProgramSearchBox extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);


      }


      render() {
        const { value, suggestions, onChange, onSuggestionSelected} = this.props;

        const inputProps = {
          placeholder: "Look Up",
          value,
          onChange: (event, { newValue, method }) => { 
              this.setState({
                value: newValue
              });
              console.log("onChange: " + JSON.stringify(newValue) );
              onChange(newValue);

          }

        };

        return (
          <Autosuggest
            suggestions={suggestions}
            onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.props.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
            onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.props.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
            onSuggestionSelected={
              (event, { suggestion, suggestionValue, suggestionIndex, sectionIndex, method }) => {

                console.log("onSuggestionSelected: " + JSON.stringify(suggestion) );
                onSuggestionSelected(suggestion);

              }
            }
            getSuggestionValue={(suggestion) => suggestion.Program}
            renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
            inputProps={inputProps}
            theme={theme}
          />
        );
      }
    }



    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
      return {
        suggestions: state.results
      };
    }
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {

      return {

        onSuggestionsFetchRequested: bindActionCreators(({ value }) => searchActions.getProgramSuggestions(value), dispatch),
        onSuggestionsClearRequested: bindActionCreators(() => searchActions.clearSuggestions(), dispatch),

      };
    }


    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProgramSearchBox);
```

Comment: Never ever dispatch from the render function, it will cause a new render, use either componentDidMount or some similar lifecycle method. If you are using redux correctly, your reducers should potentially be able to handle changes in the stores based on the action and the provider would rerender the components whos state has changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call other functions in `render()` method. Render method is responsible only for rendering views, it can be called many times and it should be as pure as possible.

**Updated answer (2019-11-21)**

Use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` lifecycle function to react to prop changes. 
It will look something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.ProgramID !== '' && prevProps.ProgramID !== this.props.ProgramID) {
        this.updateProgramId(this.props.ProgramID)
    }
}
```

**Old answer**

<strike>To do actions depending on props changing, use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` lifecycle function.</strike>

It will look something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.ProgramID !== '' && this.props.ProgramID !== nextProps.ProgramID) {
        this.updateProgramId(ProgramID)
    }
}
```

After calling `this.updateProgramId(ProgramID)` props will update and render method will be called.

More info about ReactJS lifecycle:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: deprecated, is there an other solution ?

Comment: Updated solution